# Auto-Increment Letter to specific Number

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need help at Auto-Incrementing a letter.

A description field in Table1 has values like: B39

This Table1 Record, has related records in Table2:

```
B39_a
B39_b
B39_c
B39_d
```

All I want to do is that the description in Table2 automatically takes the record at table1 and adds the specific letter. It always starts with "a" and never reaches the full alphabet.

I already tried some code from this site: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5440

```
  Function IncrementString(ByVal strString As String) As String
  '
  ' Increments a string counter
  ' e.g.  "a" -> "b"
  '             "az" -> "ba"
  '       "zzz" -> "aaaa"
  '
  ' strString is the string to increment, assumed to be lower-case alphabetic
  ' Return value is the incremented string
  '

Dim lngLenString As Long
Dim strChar As String
Dim lngI As Long

lngLenString = Len(strString)

' Start at far right
For lngI = lngLenString To 0 Step -1

' If we reach the far left then add an A and exit
If lngI = 0 Then
   strString = "a" & strString
   Exit For
End If

' Consider next character
strChar = Mid(strString, lngI, 1)
If strChar = "z" Then
  ' If we find Z then increment this to A
  ' and increment the character after this (in next loop iteration)
  strString = Left$(strString, lngI - 1) & "a" & Mid(strString, lngI + 1, lngLenString)
Else
  ' Increment this non-Z and exit
  strString = Left$(strString, lngI - 1) & Chr(Asc(strChar) + 1) & Mid(strString, lngI + 1, lngLenString)
  Exit For
End If

 Next lngI

 IncrementString = strString
 Exit Function

 End Function
```

Apparently it is not working like it should. It increases the letter, but twice! (i , i , j , j , etc.)

Description textbox (for Table2 Record ) has as default value:

```
 =IncrementString(DLast("[SeqNo]","[table2]"))
```

But like I said it increases the number by doing it double. I also have to start the process manually by entering an "a".

Comment: I would not depend on DLast() to return correct value. Records do not have inherent order. I entered "B39_zzz" and function returns "B39`aaa". Have you step-debugged?

Comment: Is this a multi-user db? Be aware there is risk multiple users could generate same SeqNo if not immediately committed to table.

Comment: What is the primary/foreign key fields in this relationship? Is there really a need for the prefix to be repeated in Table2?

Comment: This is a single user db. Its btw a GeoData db. One Record(B39 - main coordiante) has several subcoordinates called B39_a etc ... Table2 has the foreign key of table1 in it. So it can be related to each other:

Comment: That didn't really tell me what the key fields are. Why duplicate B39 in Table2? Lee Mac's function will work if don't have the **B39_** prefix as part of value passed to function. So are there other prefixes?

Comment: to visualize i made a little pic: http://epvpimg.com/Drckfab
I need the Prefix in the table2, because i need to export it to an .csv .and it need to be related to the main "B39" on a map later

Comment: Can't export a query that joins tables and concatenates the fields?

Comment: That would work ! Thats kinda more easy solution then doing it with prefix I think! But how do I get a new "letter start" every new main record then?

Comment: `strSeqNo = Nz(DMax("SeqNo", "Table2", "ID_FK =" & [ID_PK]),"")` - adjust for your field names. Now pass strSeqNo to incrementing function.

Comment: Thanks, I think the 1st line is working, but  how do I pass the var to the function of Lee Mac? Dont get it working

Comment: `IncAlpha(strSeqNo, DCount("[SeqNo]","[table2]") + 1)`

Comment: Well he does not pay attention to the ID_PK(RefrenzID) even its linked to ID_FK(test) -  so he's continuing counting with a new main record . Where do you put all the code, I think there is the mistake.. tried Textbox_AfterUpdate / Form_Enter / Textbox_DefaultValue..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191319/discussion-between-june7-and-felix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the function nor the calling code presently allows for the "A##_" prefix. If you really MUST save this prefix to Table2, code would have to be adjusted to deal with it. As is, suggest not saving the "A##" group identifier as a prefix in Table2. Use a query that joins tables on PK/FK fields to retrieve related data for export.

The DLast() search must account for the "A##" group identifier because the sequence is repeated for each group.

Unfortunately, trying to set a DefaultValue property with a dynamic parameter dependent on main form ID is impractical. For one thing, subform loads before main form so the default value cannot be built since the main form data and controls are not available. Also, when the main form is moved to a new record, again there is no data for the default value to build with. The result is error displays for the control on new record row.

Use PK/FK fields for the search.

Code in subform Current event to call your incrementing function:

```
If Me.NewRecord And Not IsNull(Me.Parent.ReferenzNR) Then
    Me!SerienBezeichnung = IncrementString(Nz(DLast("SerienBezeichnung", "tbl_GrundminenSerie", "ID_FK=" & Me.Parent.ReferenzID), ""))
End If
```

Be aware that DLast(), even though working now, could eventually fail because records do not have inherent order. An alternative would likely involve a recordset or nested domain aggregate. Example tested in VBA Immediate Window:
`?DMax("SerienBezeichnung","tbl_GrundminenSerie","ID_FK=5 AND Len([SerienBezeichnung])=" & DMax("Len([SerienBezeichnung])","tbl_GrundminenSerie","ID_FK=5"))`

Or if you feel autonumber PK can be depended on to always be increasing (which has always been my observation although there is no guarantee with autonumber):
`?DLookup("SerienBezeichnung","tbl_GrundminenSerie","ID_FK=5 AND SerienID=" & DMax("SerienID","tbl_GrundminenSerie","ID_FK=5"))`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following VBA function:

```vb
Function IncAlpha(ByVal strA As String, ByVal lngI As Long) As String
    If lngI <= 0 Then
        IncAlpha = strA
    ElseIf strA = vbNullString Then
        IncAlpha = IncAlpha("a", lngI - 1)
    Else
        lngI = lngI + Asc(Right(strA, 1)) - 97
        IncAlpha = IncAlpha(Left(strA, Len(strA) - 1), lngI \ 26) & Chr(97 + lngI Mod 26)
    End If
End Function
```

Supplied with a lowercase alphabetical string, this recursive function will increment the string by the supplied long integer argument, with `z` incrementing to `aa`, `az` incrementing to `ba` and so on.

Supplied with an empty string (`""`), the above function will return `a`.

```
?IncAlpha("", 1)
a
?IncAlpha("", 26)
z
?IncAlpha("", 27)
aa
?IncAlpha("", 42)
ap
?IncAlpha("", 314159)
qvsa
```

With this function, the suffix may therefore be calculated using:

```sql
<prefix> & IncAlpha("", DCount("[SeqNo]","[table2]") + 1)
```

Or to account for multiple prefixes:

```sql
<prefix> & IncAlpha("", DCount("SeqNo","table2","SeqNo like '" & <prefix> & "*'") + 1)
```

Comment: Including the "B39_" prefix seems to have unexpected results. Might need to adjust function to account for that. I was able to do that with the original function.

Comment: @June7 This function is to enable the OP to calculate the appropriate suffix for a new record in `Table2` - the prefix (sourced from `Table1`) may be easily concatenated to such suffix.

Comment: I know but OP is pulling last value in Table2 as basis for generating next value in sequence. Includes the prefix. Another question: do all records have the same prefix? I am guessing not.

Comment: Okay its working basically. I deleted the DefaultValue and connected my "B39" Textbox (Mainform) to my "B39_A" Textbox (Subform) and entered this code `SeqNo.Value = SeqNo.Value + "_" + IncAlpha("", DCount("[SeqNo]", "[table2]") + 1) `. He increments(!) but is not paying attention to the Prefix. If there is a new prefix like "B40" he must start with "a" again and dont continue the "B39" row.

Comment: Need to pull the max SeqNo from Table 2 associated with Prefix on main form and extract the suffix part. `strSeqNo = Nz(DMax("SeqNo", "Table2", "SeqNo LIKE '" & [Prefix] & "*'"),"")` then `If InStr(strSeqNo, "_")>0 Then strSeqNo = Mid(strSeqNo, InStr(strSeqNo,"_")+1)` Now pass strSeqNo to the incrementing function.

Comment: @Felix You can filter the `DCount` expression to count the number of records with the given prefix, e.g.: `DCount("SeqNo", "Table2", "SeqNo like '" & SeqNo.Value & "*'")`